# Invalid syntax object I/O

Tags: python, syntax

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import easygui
file = open("data.txt"[,"r+"])
Msg1 = easygui.multenterbox(title = 'ข้อมูล',fieldName=['ชื่อ','นามสกุล','ที่อยู่']
file.write(Msgl)
```

Running this code, I get the error

```
file.write(Msgl)
    ^ invalid syntax
```

It's too

```
file = open("data.txt"[,"r+"])
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Script terminated.
```

Error again. SyntaxError

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: Isn't `open('a.x'[,'r+'])` also invalid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import easygui
file = open("data.txt"[,"r+"])
Msg1 = easygui.multenterbox(title = 'ข้อมูล',fieldName=['ชื่อ','นามสกุล','ที่อยู่'])
file.write(Msgl)
```

As another poster said, you're missing a closing parenthesis, and it's wrapping to the next line causing an error.